# Using jQuery to make "scientifc plots"

Tags: jquery, plugins, plot, image-science

I have an idea. What i would like to do is to plot a skew-t diagram (scientific meteorological vertical measurement plot) with jQuery. The problem is that all the available packages are more or less for "statistical plots" like barplots and so on. I tried a few of them (the most accurate was flot - but has no option to make non-linear-background-lines or "something equal to that".

This here is an example http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cxtdm/met/snow/skewt_012205.gif

So my question. Is there any plugin i havn't seen which can do such "complex" plots? Or is there a "tutorial" for how-to-create plots from scratch? But this could be a loooooooot of work.

Thanks for your hints!
Reto, Switzerland

Answer (score 0):

I am a [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) fun it is really powerful, look at examples: [Flot Examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/), but sometimes you need to write extra code.